# Magento2 PWA Installation

Tags: magento2, pwa

**I am getting this error when I am trying to install PWA**

> /bin/sh: 1:
> /tmp/xfs-a5ee6a93/dlx-19268/.yarn/**virtual**/@magento-pwa-buildpack-virtual-b88d11cd56/4/home/ubuntu/.yarn/berry/cache/@magento-pwa-buildpack-npm-11.0.0-f451b782a9-8.zip/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/bin/buildpack:
> not found App creation cancelled.

Comment: did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

To install PWA follow the below steps

1. create Magento Project
2. After installing and setup Magento navigate the Magento directory
3. then after run the below command from Magento root directory

> yarn create @magento/pwa

If you still face App creation cancelled. issue then run above command with sudo

> sudo yarn create @magento/pwa